# How do you stop fast enumeration?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, for-in-loop, fast-enumeration

How would you stop fast enumeration once you have gotten what your looking for.

In a for loop I know you just set the counter number to like a thousand or something.
Example:

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
    if (random requirement){
        random code
        i=1000;
    }
}
```

so without converting the fast enumeration into a forward loop type thing (by comparing i to the `[array count]` how can you stop a fast enumeration in the process?

Comment: Use a `break;` statement. You can use these in your normal for-loops too.

Comment: Who told you to _reset the index variable_ in order to stop a `for` loop?! We're going to have to suspend their programming license.

Comment: Oh, well; you've now completed your re-education process and your license is again in good standing. Welcome back. /toungue-in-cheek Actually, it's better that it was you figuring that out on your own -- it's rather ingenious, if you don't know about the `break` statement.

Comment: this approach is really not that bad, as it work similar to breaking out of a while-loop, the most general loop.

Comment: @vikingosegundo while loop the most general one? I dont think so, I havent even used one while in my entire coding career

Comment: either that or im programming bad

Comment: I mean, it is the most basic one. you can write every for-loop as a while-loop. or a do-while-loop

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[from the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH7-SW30)

```
for (NSString *element in array) {
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"three"]) {
        break;
    }
}
```

if you want to end enumeration when a certain index is reached, [block-based enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000135-SW2) might be better, as it give you the index while enumerating:

```
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    //…
    if(idx == 1000) 
        *stop = YES;
}];
```

Comment: they are great and become more and more important in Apples API. you should get familiar with them.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (id object in collection) {
  if (condition_met) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just use a break statement?

```
for (int x in /*your array*/){
    if (random requirement){

        random code
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding that for nested loops, a break on an inner loop breaks just that loop. Outer loops will continue. If you want to break out completely you could do so like this:

```
BOOL flag = NO;
for (NSArray *array in arrayOfArrays) {
    for (Thing *thing in array) {
        if (someCondition) {
            // maybe do something here
            flag = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag) {
        break;
    }
}
```